# RabbitMQ/AMQP/Gearman distributing workload based on job type and grouping

Tags: multithreading, rabbitmq, amqp, gearman

I am working on a system that has lots of tasks that are perfect for queueing and has some existing home made legacy solutions already in place that work to varying degrees, I am familiar with gearman and have read through the RabbitMQ tutorials and am keen to `upgrade` the current solutions to use one of these more robust existing solutions (leaning towards rabbitMQ atm because of the flexibility and scalability and the management plugin).

I am having trouble understanding how to address a problem that allows user A to queue up a large number of a jobs (lets say 5000) of type A which then blocks the processing of any newly added jobs of type A until user A's jobs are done. Id like to implement a solution that will fairly share the load, or even just round-robin between the queued users.

Does anyone have any suggestions or insights into how I might implement a solution to this ?

I thought routing_keys might help but if User A's jobs are queued before User B adds their jobs then they still wont be processed until User A's jobs have been consumed ?

I have also thought of creating a queue for each user & jobtype but I am unsure how to do this dynamically ? 
Perhaps I need to implement some sort of control queue that sets up queues and dynamically adjusts the worker processes to consume the newly added user only queue, but would the worker collect the jobs from the queues in a round-robin type way ? And how would I decide when to remove the queues ?

thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok no comments from anyone so in the end I figured out that in rabbitmq you can consume from multiple queues in a round robin type fashion. So I built a queue that informs consumer workers to consume from a queue and dynamically create a queue for each users tasks, that are periodically deleted when empty.